# Android: Secure connection with a database

Tags: android, database, security, connection, salt

I'm developing an Android app.
When the user pushes a button, I wanna add the unique identifier of the Android device and some other data to a database.

The problem is: How can I prevent that other applications / websites etc. can put data into my database.

I was thinking about a SSL connection, but also other apps could use a SSL connection to connect to my database. The next what came up in my mind was creation an extra field, use a salt and encrypt the unique id + other data + salt and check on the db server if the encrypted information matches.

But in theory is it possible to reverse engineer an Android app, so 'they' could find my salt and also send the encrypted information to my db.

How can I make a php script to save information into a db, and make it only usable for just my own application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this data is per-device, then on first run create a "cookie", e.g. a long-enough random ID  that you use on subsequent communication with server. And also use SSL so no one can snoop on the traffic.

To generate random string use [`UUID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html).

You could use [`Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID), but if someone reverses your protocol, they could create an app that piggybacks the exploit. Unlikely but doable.

OTOH, if data is per user, then you need to create a login system.

Comment: Thnx for your answer. The problem is that I wanna add the devices to my database. I don't want the other apps can add a device to my database, just my app has the right to do that. Also I wanna get data from the database which is only accesable for my own app. Not really like a login system :)

Comment: Since you can not trust the device, you must trust the user. So you need a login system. No way around it.

Comment: I agree on that! But I'm looking for a solution to make sure the request, to post or get data, to my database comes from my own app. Not from another. It isn't even necassary that the user knows that there is a connection with my database.

Comment: You can not achieve that, because you can not trust the device. Can not be done.

Comment: You can obscure the protocol and hide the credentials in the app, but capable reverse-engineering will discover that.